# Why does sizeof("string") prints one more than the length of "string"?

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int a = sizeof("string");
        printf("%d", a );
        return 0;
}
```

The above code prints 7 as the output while the length of string is only 6. Could someone please explain?

Comment: "string" end with an '\0'

Comment: maybe the hidden null character added to the end counts as a byte? Normally when you use sizeof, you use it on some kind of variable, not a fixed value.

Comment: @Mike `sizeof` works equally well on variables, values, and types. For all three, it only evaluates the ___type___ of the expression (at compile-time).

Answer (score 11):

This is what is happening:

- The string literal `"string"` is an array of (`const`) char, including a null-terminator character, i.e. `{'s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0'}`. In your example, said array has 7 elements.
- The operator `sizeof` when applied to an array yields its size in bytes.
- The size of an array is the sum of the size of each of its elements.
- The size of one `char` is 1.

So, you get the number of chars explicit in the literal, plus a null-terminator.

This behaviour is the same in both C and C++

Answer (score 4):

All strings in c, even the ones you write like `"string"` are terminated with a null byte `'\0'`.

The expression `"string"` in c or c++ code is considered a string literal, that means a char array that looks like this: `{'s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'}`. In c and c++ all strings must be terminated by a null byte in memory, otherwise functions cannot identify their end.

This is, by the way, also why you must add 1 character when calculating lenght of character arrays in c code to account for the null byte. So if you want to store `"string"` in a character array that you declare, you would have to do `char array[7];` using 6 here would lead to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The length of the string is 6 and the null character is also added by default when we specify the string in "". So it prints 7.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are null-terminated and stored as an array containing the characters and terminated with a null character (`'\0'`, called NUL in ASCII). So you have:

```
s | t | r | i | n | g | \0 | 
                         ^-- 7th char
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `"string"` is implicitly adding a `'\0'` character.